# How can I find the value of x corresponding to half the maximum value of y in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to get the half life of a process by finding the time corresponding the half the maximum value of the y-variable and apply it across different cases. I have tried two variations of the which() in R but non of them give me the result I want.

```
#rc and time are columns of a data.frame

time[which.max(rc)] # gives the time at rc-max, but i need the time at half rc-max

time[which(rc==max(rc)/2] #returns numeric(0)
```

what can I do to get this value so that I can apply to other cases?

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example along with the output that you expect based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
time <- 1:10                                  #sample data
rc <- exp(-(1:10))

uniroot(                                      #finds roots of functions
        approxfun(time, rc - max(rc) / 2),    #linear interpolation function
        range(time)                           #range of values to check
        )$root                                #value of time where rc=max(rc)/2

[1] 1.790988
```

See the help pages for these functions for further details and options

Comment: thank you for the quick response. this is the solution to my proble